# get Dates In Range in rescript and Daylight Saving Time

Tags: reactjs, date, time, rescript

i have a calendar in my site which take a start date and end date and pass them into a function who calculates  the dates between .
lets sat we have the start date `Mon Mar 29 2021 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)` and the end date is `Mon Apr 05 2021 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)`  ; this function should return ["30/3/2021","31/3/2021","1/4/2020","2/4/2020","3/4/2020","4/4/2020"]

```
let getDatesInRange = (start, end) => {
  let dates = ref([])
  let current = ref(start)

  while current.contents <= end {
    dates := dates.contents->Js.Array2.concat([current.contents->toUTCDateString])
    current := {
        let date = current.contents->toUTCDateString->Js.Date.fromString
        date->Js.Date.setDate(date->Js.Date.getDate +. 1.0)->ignore

        date
      }
  }

  dates.contents
}
```

and this is toUTCDateString function which take a date and give the string version of it

```
let toUTCDateString = date => {
  let date = date->External.unSafeCastToJsObject

  date["toISOString"]()["split"]("T")[0]
}
```

These functions where working fine until The time has changed for Daylight Saving Time; we gain an hour so the day stuck there in for some reason
Any body face this issue before and who to deal with such time issues ?

Comment: in regular js I would ask why you just weren't using the `toLocaleDateString` function I do not know rescript so I'm sure you must have your reasons